# Django REST Framework Web Login not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I can't seem to figure out why my rest framework login in my django project won't work... I have got the log in link there and all and it does redirect me to the rest login page but after filling in my credentials and clicking login it just takes me back to the page I came from but it does not seem to authenticate me as it still says "Login" in the top right corner...

[image: This is the login button I am talking about.]

I would expect it to change to "admin" in this case as I am trying to login using my superuser named "admin"...

I am surely missing something..

Here are my REST **Urls**

```
path("rest/auctions", auction_list, name="auction-list"),
path('rest/auctions/<int:pk>', auction_detail, name="auction-detail"),
path('rest-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

The rest-auth/ one I know is the one that somehow adds the login button and all (Magic?) But maybe I have to do something else too to make it authenticate? I don't know... I am using the built in django authentication system and User model.

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def auction_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            auctions = Auction.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query), deadline__gte=timezone.now(),
                                              status=Auction.STATUS_ACTIVE)
        else:
            auctions = Auction.objects.all()
        serializer = AuctionSerializer(auctions, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AuctionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    winning_bid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True, slug_field='amount', allow_null=True)
    seller = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True, slug_field='username', allow_null=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title', 'description', 'deadline', 'min_price', 'winning_bid', 'seller')
```

in my **Settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Lastly I can mention that the authentication works when I use the API via Postman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove BasicAuthentication from the settings.py and it should work as expected. BasicAuthentication works by base64 encoding the user login information and attaching them to HTTP Authorization Header. That's why your requests via Postman work normally.

By default Django uses Session based authentication, which depends on cookies on the client to store the user session information once the user is logged in. Obviously username and password are not stored in cookie with BasicAuthentication.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
    ],
}
```

Comment: Would you look at that. That was easy. Thanks! :) I suppose Postman's "Basic Auth" is not the same as "Basic Authentication" :P I thought removing that line would give me no ways to authenticate. I was wrong. Massive thanks.

Answer (score 21):

If the other solution doesn't work, add this line too

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

Comment: Adding this code to my settings solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an updated version of the accepted answer here is in need:

you can actually make use of both SessionAuthentication and BasicAuthentication by having:

`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
}`

in your settings.py

If Basic fails, Django will look if there is a session there